# Postfix TLS: Examples for problems when using client certificates

Tags: postfix, starttls

The Postfix documentation states the following with regards to the parameter for client certificates, [smtp_tls_cert_file](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_cert_file):

> #### smtp_tls_cert_file (default: empty)
>
> [...]
> Do not configure client certificates unless you must present client TLS certificates to one or more servers. Client certificates are not usually needed, and can cause problems in configurations that work well without them. The recommended setting is to let the defaults stand:

(note this is for `smtp_tls_cert_file` not smtp**d**).

"can cause problems in configurations that work well without them" is quite vague.
What could be possible examples where configuring client certificate and key files could lead to problems?

A possible example config in `main.cf` could be the following

```
smtp_tls_cert_file=$smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_key_file=$smtpd_tls_key_file
```

Comment: Try and see. Sometimes mail clients don't know there could be a certificate so with such a client you'll be unable to connect to otherwise functional server — it's nowhere to configure. Also, notice you only may request certificates in `submission` (or/and `smtps`) service running at tcp port 587 (465). Never do that with the default smtpd running on port 25; that **will** break the email delivery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1: Someone might require that if you do present a client certificates you do so on a TLS1.3 channel, and reject clients sending them on TLS1.0 channels. While permitting TLS1.0 channels otherwise, for unauthenticated submission.

Example 2: A broken proxy or firewall somewhere between your smtp client and its peer might choke on certain transport features or properties of certificates. The operator might not be aware of or care about that breakage, because it affects neither unauthenticated submission, nor the peers he actually did issue certificates to.

Configuring client certificates makes you *opt in* to additional restrictions (possibly non-obvious, depending on your TLS toolkit, your peers TLS toolkit, and your peers local policy) that you should avoid except for those cases where you actually need that feature.

Conditional access restrictions are somewhat tricky to configure, so what admins will routinely do is: Enforce all their mTLS-related rules, for all client certificates, always: even when that certificate was not required. Which ends up refusing clients based on their certificates.. even in cases straight up *ignoring* the certificate would have been fine. Why can they do this? Because it is just that uncommon for anyone to configure client certificates unless they do have a specific agreement with the other party. Because they can safely assume, that *if* you are sending a certificate at all, you are one of those known parties that can and should be expected to also follow their policies in other areas.

|  | your configuration matches client cert requirements | your configuration is fails to meet other client cert requirements |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no cert, none expected | works | works |
| no cert, optional | works | works |
| you send a cert to a party expecting it | works (certificate used) | rejected (as per agreement with issuer) |
| you send a cert to a party not expecting it | might work (cert ignored) | **Oh no! Your connection has been rejected for extra rules regarding a feature you need not have used.** |

Recommendation: Configure it only if you need it, and ideally stick to common and easily configured cases of *never* or *always* (to single relay host) sending client certificates.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive and well written answer.